# New Fiber Optic Internet Connection, want to use Sonicwall TZ200 as main router, WAN/VLAN

Tags: sonicwall, fiber, internet

Key Facts:

- We have a new internet connection with Movistar.
- It is a 100/10 Mbit line.
- We want to use the TZ200 as our main router.
- The Fiber Optic router is a ONT I240
- The internet router that movistar supplies you with is a Irouter 1104w

We DO NOT want to use the "irouter 1104w". We want to use out router the Sonicwall TZ200.

Here is the configuration file of the "irouter 1104w".

```
Name: Internet
Description: 6
VLAN tag:6
VLAN priority:1
NAT type: Symmetric
Input route protocol: None
Trigger: Always On
Username: xxxx
Password: xxxx
AC name
Service name
Enable DNS override
DMZ address
Reset connection
Enable connection: Yes
```

When setting up the PPPoe on the Sonicwall, there is no information about the VLAN stuff and it does not work. It tries then disconnects.

**Questions**

1. Does anyone have any information regarding the above matter? Or better a solution
2. Can/should I use all 3 routers (uff) - ONT I240 > Irouter 1104w > Sonicwall TZ200?
3. If I were to do number 2, will this have an effect on the performance. Also to note I would then have 3 points of failure.

***Update 09/03/2012***

**Key Updates:**

- I had spoken with the ISP (Movistar) and they have told me that I do not need the information regarding VLANs in the configuration, however I tested this theory by removing the VLAN setting (OEM Movistar Router) and leaving it blank. The internet did not work, therefor the VLAN information is very important!
- The Movistar router does not support bridge mode :(
- Today I went out an bought 3 Ethernet routers. (Cisco (E4200-EZ), ovislink (EVOw300AR) and sitecom 150N). Tried to setup PPPOE, none of them worked, there was no setting for VLAN that I could see

**Some little success, if you want to call it that.**

I have tried the 3 router setup - NT I240 > Irouter 1104w > Sonicwall TZ200. Following results by setting a static IP in the Sonicwall TZ200.

TEST CASE 1 **NT I240 > Irouter 1104w**

1. Speednet.com (50.2Mbit / 5.01 Mbit)
2. Download Vista SP1 (5.5MB a sec)

TEST CASE 2 **NT I240 > Irouter 1104w > Sonicwall TZ200**

1. Speednet.com (10.1Mbit / 5.01 Mbit)
2. Download Vista SP1 (1.7MB a sec)

As you can see from the above... Test case 2 is no acceptable. If anyone can help, pleas let me know. I will continue to search on.

***Update 09/03/2012 even more***

Ok, I think I am getting somewhere, I think. On another forum there is this message:

> I use 802.1q tag, otherwise the ONT doesn't respond to any request.

Now the sonicwall TZ200 has 802.1q, it states (Enable 802.1q tagging).

If anyone has any knowledge of this. Please advise.

***Update 09/03/2012 evening ( 28 hours no sleep)***

**Key Note to help**

- For some unknown reason you need to have VLAN 6 ID in the frame header or the fiber optic router will not respond.
- Sonic wall level 2 engineers are baffled about about this, PPPOE with VLAN ID is a strange one, but I suggest you become aware of it because of FTTH.
- Not sure is 802.1p can do what we need.

Comment: I'm willing to bet a call to your ISP would solve this the fastest.

Comment: @Safado - You would think so, however this has been tried. I had to explain to them that I wanted the username and password to the router they provided me, that in its self took about 30 minutes, they were asking me why etc... I am going to try again this weekend of course, but in the mean time, and help is welcomed...

Comment: Ask the ISP if the Irouter can be put in bridged mode.  This will allow it to pass traffic straight through to the TZ200.  Also, does the TZ200 have the latest firmware?

Comment: @JimG - Hi Jim, I have access to the routers admin panel and I cannot find anything about bridge mode in the settings. The TZ200 has the latest firmware. I did it last time.

Comment: I second Jim's suggestion. At one of my remote sites this is what we do. The modem from the ISP is put into bridged mode, our TZ150 plugs into it and we establish the PPPoE connection from the SonicWall. However, given that they've provided you with two devices, their set up might be different.

Comment: Had updated notes above. Please let me know... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of testing and research, a solution is here. A Mikrotik Routerboard RB250GS or a Smart Switch which allows you to create VLANS.

Effectively

Tested on a Netgear 724T Smart Switch & Mikrotik Routerboard RB250GS

1. Login to your switch in the switch (Netgear 724T) and create a VLAN named "WAN" with an ID of 6.
2. On VLAN6 set one of the ports to be Untagged and the other to be
   Tagged
3. On VLAN1 remove any membership for these ports, usually you can click the port until it doesnt have a U or a T
4. On PVID configuration set both to be PVID 6 (sets default VLAN to 6 on both ports)
5. Plug the X1 WAN port of your sonicwall into the Untagged port
6. Plug the Router interface into the Tagged port
7. At this point your router will be happy as it will see a tagged interface at the other end of the cable

Thanks to Damo and a Spanish forum.

Comment: UPDATE, the DPI/UTM service will only give you 10% of your total bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not uncommon, a lot of FTTH services in the Netherlands require you to set up PPPoE on VLAN 6 as well. Just create a VLAN interface on port X1 (it will be called X1.6) and configure your PPPoE on that. Make sure the routes send traffic from X0 to X1.6 instead of X1 and you're fine. No need to put switches in between.